# Variable not accessible across Netbeans Form

Tags: java, netbeans, media, public

I wrote a media player in Java using the Java Media Framework (yeah, I know it's really old!)
on Netbeans, and I have this problem:
I have a browse button which selects the file, initializes the Player and starts playback. The problem is, the button is in private void and hence the player is not accessible across the form.
This is the jButton code:

```
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
Player pla;
try{
   FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.show();
String filename = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
pla=Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator("file:///"+filename));


pla.start();

}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

How do I make the player pla across the Jpanel so that any button in the panel (Netbeans automatically sets all jButtons to private void) can access the player pla?

P.S.: Someone please suggest me a modern API (other than Xuggler) for Java media, preferably, using FFMPEG but not necessarily.

Thanks!

Comment: The same way you would in *any* class; declare `Player pla` as a field in your class rather than a local variable inside this method.

Answer (score 0):

The class player can have a method

By reflexion you can return any button

```
JButton getButton(String nameButton) throws Exception{
    Field field = clazz.getClass().getField(nameButton);
    return (JButton) field.get(this);

}
```